# jquery unable to show and hide an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have `div` element as

`<div class="preview-image hide"><img src="{{STATIC_URL}}ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif"></div>`

The `hide` class belongs to Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2, the `preview-image` basically adds some styling to the element and used as handle for JavaScript.

I have jQuery code as below where

`$loading.show()` and `$loading.hide()` are not working.

The surprising this is when I run `$preview.parent().find('.preview-image').show()` from console, its working!!

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {

    var SET_TIME = 6000;

    $('[data-preview]').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $preview = $('#' + $this.data('presponse'));
        var $loading = $preview.parent().find('.preview-image');
        $loading.show();

        $.ajax({

        });

        $loading.hide(); 
    });
});
})(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$.ajax()` is an asynchronous call, the `$loading.hide()` is being called (as it appears to the user) immediately after the `$loading.show()`. In order to circumvent this, you should make the `$loading.hide()` call after your AJAX call is complete. One way to do this is:

```
var $loading = $preview.parent().find('.preview-image');
$loading.show();

$.ajax({

}).always(function() {
    $loading.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that it's hiding straight away? I think the hide needs to be within a success function of the AJAX call rather than being after it.

Eg.

```
$.ajax({
    success: function() {
        $loading.hide();    
    }
});
```

Comment: actually, the dom initially hides the element using `hide` class. jquery first needs to show it and later hide back!